# Junit and Spring dependencies

Tags: spring, junit

Do junit does not support the injection of beans to the lower level in an MVC architecture?

ie : when I want to access to my service from my classTest, it gives me nullpointerException when the service classe try to access to a bean dao 
I do not know where is the problem, plz someone can help 
Thank you

My config :

Test class :

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

 @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test-config.xml")

 public class Case1Test extends Mockito {

 @Autowired
 UserServiceImpl userService;


 @Test
 public final void testInit() {
 String username = "abc";
 String prenom = userService.findByUserName(username);

assertEquals(prenom, "Hajar");
}
}
```

My service:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService  {
private static final Logger LOG
=LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);
 public UserServiceImpl() {

 LOG.info("Initializing {}", UserServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName());
 }

 private UserDao userDao;

public UserDao getUserDao() {
return userDao;
  }

@Autowired (required=false)
public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
this.userDao = userDao;
}

@Override
 public String findByUserName(String username) {

String prenom = userDao.findByUserName(username).getPrenom();


return prenom;
}


  }
```

And my DAO :

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

private static final Logger LOG =LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

public UserDaoImpl() {

 LOG.info("Initializing {}", UserDaoImpl.class.getSimpleName());
 }

 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Transactional
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public User findByUserName(String username) {

  List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
  users = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where
  username=?")
        .setParameter(0, username).list();

  if (users.size() > 0) {
    return users.get(0);
  } else {
    return null;
  }

   }


public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;
}
@Autowired (required=false)
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public Session getCurrentSession()  {
if ( this.sessionFactory == null ) {
System.out.println("session NULLL");
}

 Session session;
 try {
    session =  this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() ;
 } catch(HibernateException e ){

    session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
  }

        return session  ;
  }


     }
```

test-config.xml is :

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


 <bean class="fr.service.UserServiceImpl"></bean>


    </beans>
```

and my context.xml :

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
 <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataBase.driver}"/>
 <property name="url" value="${dataBase.url}"/>
 <property name="username" value="${dataBase.user}"/>
<property name="password" value="${dataBase.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="mappingLocations"
 value="classpath*:/orm/*.hbm.xml"/>

<property name="hibernateProperties">

    <props>
        <prop
 key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

    </props>

 </property>

 </bean>
```

I have NullPointerException when my Service class (UserServiceImpl ) try to access to a dao bean in this line : String prenom = userDao.findByUserName(username).getPrenom(); from UserServiceImpl class

Comment: How are you running tests?  Junit out of the box will not wire up spring beans.

Comment: Iadded the configuration above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where is your config actually including your context.xml?
I don't see it, and thus your context for your testcase only contains those beans defined in your `test-config.xml` which is only a userservice...

If you want your dao to be wired into your service, it should be on a classpath scan, or included in your `test-config.xml`

Comment: I added <bean id="userDao" class="fr.dao.UserDaoImpl"/> in test-config.xml and it works! thank you